# list size of folders and their changed date

Tags: files

How can I list the size of folders as well as their changed date?

I am able to get the size of folders using `du`.
I am also able to list the folders together with their date using

```
$ls  -ltr $path |  grep '^d'
```

But I cannot display the size and the date together.

`ls -h` or `stat` do not work for me.

Comment: Are you after a du-style sizing with modification time, or an `ls` style "directory size"?

Comment: I'd say ls style "directory size"

Answer (score 6):

On a GNU system, `man du` reveals `--time` argument:

```
du -h --time .
```

which for directories shows the time of the last modification of any file in the directory, or any of its subdirectories.

Comment: --time is not available for my version

Comment: Maybe something like `find . -type d | xargs -I'{}' bash -c "stat --printf='%y ' {} & du -sh {}"`

Answer (score 1):

Don't parse `ls` it's bad juju. My first start would be - use `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

for ( grep { -d } glob ( "*") ) {
    print join ( "\t", $_, -s, (stat)[9] ),"\n";
}
```

But this of course, just takes the inode side of the directory, which is probably not what you want. So instead ... actually our easiest might actually be to call `du` anyway.

```
for my $dir ( grep { -d } glob ( "*") ) {
    print join ( "\t", (stat $dir)[9], `du -sh $dir`,  );
}
```

Or perhaps making use of the `Filesys::DiskUsage` module.

But as a one liner:

```
perl -e 'for ( grep {-d} glob ( "*" ) ) { print join "\t", (stat)[9], `du -sh $_` }'
```

Edit: With formatted timestamps:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -e 'for ( grep {-d} glob ( "*" ) ) { print join "\t", Time::Piece->new((stat)[9])->strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), `du -sh $_` }'
```

Edit: Version older than 5.9.5 (which you should really consider upgrading, given it's well past EOL):

```
perl -MPOSIX -e 'for ( grep {-d} glob ( "*" ) ) { print join "\t", strftime("%Y-%m-%d",gmtime((stat)[9]))), `du -sh $_` }'
```

Comment: perl works great it would be useful to display the seconds in a readable format (for example in mm-dd-yyyy). I have tried to add "+%m/%d/%y" to (stat)[9], but it does not work

Comment: Easy enough. Added.

Comment: not so in my case :( - Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC .... Is there a way to maybe download it ?

Comment: Yes, but it's been core in perl since 5.9.5 - which is quite an old version. You could probably use POSIX instead though.

Comment: now it works , after removing one extra parentheses from  strftime("%Y-%m-%d",gmtime((stat)[9])))

Comment: with the mention that it only works if the folder name does not contain SPACE

Comment: the `du` part, yes. The stat should work fine though.

Comment: Can always wrap directory name in double quotes it this prospect bothers you.