# List directories created in the last 3 days and display space usage

Tags: bash, solaris

As part of disk clean-up, I am now required to delete all folders and its content created in the last 3 days (not the current business date):

Example - today's date is 20191121, then:

```
/opt/png/wsm/data/workdir/batch/*20191120*
/opt/png/wsm/data/workdir/batch/*20191119*
/opt/png/wsm/data/workdir/batch/*20191118*
```

All I can do now is get the list:

```
ls -d */ | grep 20191118 (and then 19 and 20)
```

How I can check how much size I can save
by deleting a particular dated folder(s) & its content?

bash version on the server is:

```
bash-3.2$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (i386-pc-solaris2.10)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: What Solaris are you running and do you have GNU tools available (Solaris 11.4 has, but I'm not sure what version you have; Solaris 11.4 also has `bash` 4.4.19).

Answer (score 0):

When cleaning files and folders, you might want to use the `du` command.

`du` lists drive space usage, [has a `--time` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250902/279016), and can be used [for directories only](https://superuser.com/a/322539/1003167). Combining them:

```
du -h */ --time | grep -E '2019\-09\-(18|19|20)'
```

This will grab any subdirectory which has had its contents last created or modified on november 18th, 19th or 20th. It'll output the size (`-h` human readable), modification date, and finally the path.

Comment: bash-3.2$ du -h */ --time | grep -E '2019\-09\-(18|19|20)'
grep: illegal option -- E
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: Apparently we have different versions of `grep`.. Can you use `egrep` instead? or just `grep`?
I need to specify the `-E` option to get regular expression matching working (to match on either 18, 19 or 20)

Comment: removing -E from grep.  but not getting consolidated result : du -h */ --time | grep '2019\-09\-(18|19|20)'
bash-3.2$ du -h */ --time | grep '2019\-11\-(18|19|20)'
bash-3.2$ du -h */ --time | grep '20191117'
  44M   BLOOMBERG.DIF.equity_option_open_us.20191117.001
  76M   BLOOMBERG.OUT.gics.20191117.001
   0K   FUNDRUN.ADHOC1.20191117_220401/acbl_out
   0K   FUNDRUN.ADHOC1.20191117_220401/amdpr_out/partial
   1K   FUNDRUN.ADHOC1.20191117_220401/amdpr_out/done
   3K   FUNDRUN.ADHOC1.20191117_220401/amdpr_out
 5.4M   FUNDRUN.ADHOC1.20191117_220401
   0K   sc_run_bbps/20191117

Comment: this command is working du -ah */ --time | grep '2019111[7-9]'
 but the it produces a huge list of directories rather than giving total size.

Comment: rm command will fail if number of directories and files is over 5000. Use find instead (refer to my answer below)

Comment: @Loke12k Since the fairly commonly supported command `grep -E` does not work for you, could you please update the text in the question with information about what type of Unix environment you are using? It is obviously not a recent Linux, nor macOS or any of the BSDs...

Comment: @Kusalananda 
bash-3.2$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (i386-pc-solaris2.10)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 0):

On the 22nd of November 2019, the following code will create a string in `$pattern` that will be `20191121|20191120|20191119`.  It does this using one call to GNU `date` to get the dates, and then concatenates the results with `|` as a delimiter. Note that the default `date` utility on Solaris can not be used like this, which is why we use `gdate` (GNU `date`'s name on Solaris, by default).

```bash
readarray -t dates < <(
cat <<END_DATE_INPUT | gdate -f - +'%Y%m%d'
1 day ago
2 days ago
3 days ago
END_DATE_INPUT
)

pattern=$( IFS='|';  printf '%s' "${dates[*]}" )
```

This can be used as an extended shell globbing pattern in `bash` to delete the wanted directories based on their names, and also to show their sizes (with `du`):

```
shopt -s extglob
du -s -h /opt/png/wsm/data/workdir/batch/*@($pattern)*/
#rm -r -f /opt/png/wsm/data/workdir/batch/*@($pattern)*/
```

If you have many thousands of these directories, use a loop:

```
shopt -s extglob
for dirpath in /opt/png/wsm/data/workdir/batch/*@($pattern)*/
do
    du -s -h "$dirpath"
    #rm -r -f "$dirpath"
done
```

You may well want to test this with `rm` replaced by `echo` before running it "live".

---

If you have access to the `zsh` shell (which you do have on Solaris), and you're happy with working by the last-modified timestamp on the directories (i.e. the time at which something was most recently added or deleted in the directory):

```
du -s -h /opt/png/wsm/data/workdir/batch/*(/m-3m+0)
```

(and similarly for `rm`).

The glob qualifier `(/m-3m+0)` makes the preceding pattern only match directories that were modified within the last three days, but more than a day ago.  Note that this does not use the filenames of the directories.

Comment: rm command will fail if number of directories and files is over 5000. Use find instead (refer to my answer below)

Comment: @NathaelPajani No `find` call necessary. See update.

Comment: You're right if the goal is to remove the whole directory, which seems to be the case. But why trying to avoid find ?

Comment: @NathaelPajani I'm not _avoiding_ `find`. It's just not necessary to use it. We know exactly where the directories are, and how to match them with a globbing pattern. We just need to figure out what the dates should be that goes into the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer will fail if the directories you try to rm contain more than 5000 files.
This will leave you with old undeleted directories.

Use find instead with "-exec rm {} \+" which will call rm one or more times with a maximum of 5000 args for each call.

In order to find files/directories modified, use find

```
find . -type d -atime n  # for exact number of days
find . -type d -atime +n  # for greater than n days
```

You can add -daystart option to measure times from the beginning of today rather than from 24 hour ago

Then, use either "-exec rm {} \+"  to remove or "-exec du -sh {} \;" to get disk usage of each directory.

Also consider -maxdepth option for find + du calls to limit find to directories at top level.

Refer to "man find" for more information (from terminal (best) or from man7.org to get an up-to-date man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html, but not from Die.net (they even strip the page timestamps so you don't know their man pages or years old and outdated)).

Comment: the below 2 not producing any result: bash-3.2$ find . -type d -atime 3
bash-3.2$ find . -type d -atime +3 ; however when i try -3 ti give me list of all folders including today's

Comment: Note that if you base the deletion on the access timestamp, just doing an `ls` in a directory may update this. You also have to be in the correct directory to run your given code, or you will delete the wrong things.  If you delete directories with `find` and `rm`, you may want to add `-depth` to do a depth-first traversal, or use `-prune` to not enter the found directories. You may also want to restict the deletion to avoid deleting directories access before three days age.

Comment: @Loke12k : -3 is "less than three days", +3 is "more than three days" and 3 is "exactly three days". What you are looking for seems to be +1 (more than one day).

Comment: @Kusalananda : you're right about access time. A solution would be to use a filesystem mounted with noatime option then access time will not be a problem.

Comment: @Loke12k : I did not provide an exact solution as I do not have access to your exact configuration. I only pointed to some tracks so you can find a solution and learn at the same time. If you need exact solution, I can provide paid support :)

Comment: On Solaris (which the user is using), the GNU `find` command is called `gfind` and is documented in `man gfind`.  The benefit of looking at a manual on your own system with `man` is that you get the manual for the actual utility that is available on your system, not some random variant that may be available on some other person's machine.

Answer (score 0):

Then a much shorter and (from my point of view) more readable syntax for @Kusalananda solution, and using date instead of gdate (though maybe gdate is a date equivalent on solaris ?):

```
days=$(echo -e "1 day ago \n 2 days ago \n 3 days ago" | date -f - +'%Y%m%d')
dpath="/opt/png/wsm/data/workdir/batch"
for day in $days ; do
    du -s -h "$dpath/$day"
    rm -r -f "$dpath/$day"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Solaris system has `bash`, then it will typically have zsh as well.

Since that date format happens to sort like numbers, you could use zsh's `<start-end>` decimal number range glob operator:

```
zsh -c '
  zmodload zsh/datetime
  now=$EPOCHSECONDS day=$(( 24 * 60 * 60 ))
  for var t (start $(( now - 3*day )) end $(( now - 1*day )) )
    strftime -s $var %Y%m%d $t
  range="<$start-$end>"
  rm -rf -- *$~range*(/)
'
```

Beware that if run on the wrong day of the year in the middle of the night when switching from/to summer time, subtracting 24*60*60 seconds from the current time might land you on the same day or 2 days ago.

To get the `c`umulative disk usage of those directories replace `rm -rf` with `du -c`. Whether that's the amount of space that will be reclaimed after you remove them depends on whether any files in those directories have hardlinks elsewhere or not.